# How can I get the last two numbers before a string with regex python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a pattern that is like `1 0 0 1 254.79 529 Tm`. I would like to get the `254.79` and `529` (last to numbers before the `Tm`). I did a regex that is able to extract the number `529` with `\b\d+(?=\s*Tm)`, but I can't manage to get the `254.79`.

How can I extract the last two numbers that are before the Tm? The numbers could be with or without decimals.

Comment: How about `[0-9.]+\s+[0-9.]+(?=\s*Tm)`?

Comment: Hi @joanis. Yes, this did the trick! Would you mind in explaining this and also put your answer below, so I can accept it :)

Comment: `(?=...)` does look ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression should do the trick:

```
[0-9.]+\s+[0-9.]+(?=\s*Tm)
```

Explanation:

- I use `[0-9.]+` to capture one number, which I'm loosely defining as a sequence of one or more digits or dots. It's a bit lax, since it would also accept `3.4.5`. You'll need a stricter RE if you want to exclude this. See other answers to this question for such strict REs.
- I use `\s+` to match one or more spaces between the two numbers.
- I kept your original loop-ahead for find `Tm` at the end after 0 or more spaces.

PS: This answer duplicates some of the other answers already provided, but at the request of OP, I am upgrading my initial comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a lookahead assertion here.  This regex:

`/([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+Tm/`

matches your input.  Here is a regex101 playground where you can experiment with it:

https://regex101.com/r/7DXK3E/1

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple code python. You can refer:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"((\d+)[.](\d+))(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)Tm")
test_str = "1 0 0 1 254.79 529 Tm"
m_test = regex.search(test_str)

if m_test is not None:
    print(m_test[1])
    print(m_test[5])
```

Image result: [image: Result]

You can try your ideas at regex101. Here is an example I did for you, I think this should be enough for you to upgrade yourself.

https://regex101.com/r/upLSG4/1

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the lookahead to get the match only, there should be an optional part in the lookahead before matching  `Tm`

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\s+Tm\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zFfGgz/1)

Another option is to use 2 capture groups.

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) Tm\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture a digit with an optional part in group 1
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture a digit with an optional part in group 2
- `\s+Tm\b` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `Tm` and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcM4f2/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) Tm\b"
s = "1 0 0 1 254.79 529 Tm"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('254.79', '529')]
```